# Having trouble downloading the extention pack for virtual box (windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

Brand new windows user here. I have successfully installed Virtual Box 5.1.8, and I'm having trouble downloading the extension pack. This is on a completely brand new machine with windows 10 installed (some sort of HP laptop that I grabbed from Sam's Club on Wednesday). I downloaded the extension pack from [this page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). I am the only user on the machine and I believe I have administrator privileges.

I run the extension pack (called `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.8-111374`)  by double clicking on the icon from the Downloads folder, and it seems to open up Virtual Box automatically and it prompts me with a prompt, asking me whether I want to install the extension pack or cancel. I click install, agree to the VirtualBox license, and I'm met with this error:

```
Failed to install the Extension Pack 
C:/Users/Nick/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.8-111374.vbox-extpack.

The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp.exe: error: Failed to rename 
the temporary directory to the final one: VERR_ACCESS_DENIED 
('C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ExtensionPacks\Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-_-
inst-12020' -> 
'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ExtensionPacks\Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack')


rcExit=1.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ExtPackManagerWrap
Interface: IExtPackManager {edba9d10-45d8-b440-1712-46ac0c9bc4c5}
```

So, there seems to be some sort of permissions issue. But I'm confused by the fact that I am the only user on this machine and I am an administrator, so there should be no issue. Secondly, no such temporary directory exists when I look after the failed install, so either there is some sort of automatic cleanup on error or there is a previous error of not creating the temporary folder in the first place not being caught by the install process (might also be a permissions error).

I will update this post with other attempts to solve the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your VB version?

Comment: 5.1.8 (updated question)

Comment: Install it with  administrator privileges , Right clic and run as admin

Comment: This is not given as an option on the installer when I right click. I can open virtual box as an admin, but then there's no way (that I can see) to open the installer from virtual box, and if I simply have virtual box running and attempt to open the installer then it opens a new instance of virtual box and doesn't use the virtual box that's being run as an admin. Aside question - shouldn't things automatically run as admin?

Comment: How to resolve this issue? I am using Windows 10 and then latest VirtualBox executable and extension 5.1.12-112440; I tried even installing virtualBox with administrator but of no use.

Comment: I was never able to solve it. Ended up getting my mac fixed and it works on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

You cam manually install the extension pack if the double click and selecting 'Install' fails.  From in the app, choose File –> Preferences in menu, then select Extensions option in VirtualBox console. From here you can browse the downloaded extension pack and install it on Windows 10.

[image: vb_ui]